# XSLT 1.0 Muenchian grouping implementation is not working

Tags: xml, xslt

Working XSLT 2.0 implementation:

```
<xsl:template name="SummaryRows">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//Item/ItemGroup/ItemEntry" group-by="Description">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:call-template name="formatNumber2">
                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="format-number(number(sum(current-group()/ItemSum/text())), '#.##')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Attempt to implement [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:key name="items-by-description" match="ItemEntry" use="Description"/>
<xsl:template name="SummaryRows">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Item/ItemGroup/ItemEntry[count(. | key('items-by-description', Description)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="current-grouping-key" select="Description"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('items-by-description', $current-grouping-key)"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$current-grouping-key"/>
                        </td>
                        <td/>
                        <td align="right">
                                <xsl:call-template name="formatNumber2">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="format-number(number(sum(./ItemSum/text())), '#.##')"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Example xml snippet:

```
     <Item>
      <ItemGroup groupId="1">
        <ItemEntry>
          <Description>A</Description>
          <ItemSum>6301.1</ItemSum>
        </ItemEntry>
        <ItemEntry>
          <Description>B</Description>
          <ItemSum>901.1</ItemSum>
        </ItemEntry>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup groupId="2">
        <ItemEntry>
          <Description>C</Description>
          <ItemSum>631.1</ItemSum>
        </ItemEntry>
        <ItemEntry>
          <Description>A</Description>
          <ItemSum>9.1</ItemSum>
        </ItemEntry>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Item>
```

It should return list of `ItemEntry`'s `Description` (that suppose to be current-grouping-key() in xslt 2.0). For each such group it has to have sum of all `ItemSum` of that group.

Example result:

```
    A           6310.2
    B           901.1
    C           631.1
```

The `<xsl:for-each select="$current-group">` loop is not executed resulting in empty set.  What is the implementation missing?

Update:

The environment is Java 8

Transformation factory properties / initialization:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
            System.setProperty(XPathFactory.DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME + ":" + XPathFactory.DEFAULT_OBJECT_MODEL_URI,
                    "org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl");

            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
```

Comment: You will have to show minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you get and the one you want. If the XSLT 2 outputs a `tr` row for each group I don't understand the inner `xsl:for-each select="$current-group"` in your XSLT 1 as that way you would output a `tr` for each item in each group. And the `sum(current-group()/ItemSum/text())` would be `sum($current-group/ItemSum/text())` if I were to transcribe the XSLT 2 to XSLT 1 using the variable you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you don't need two nested `for-each` elements to replace a single `for-each-group`, you just use one, then a minimal sample would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

<xsl:key name="items-by-description" match="ItemEntry" use="Description"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Item/ItemGroup/ItemEntry[count(. | key('items-by-description', Description)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="current-grouping-key" select="Description"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('items-by-description', $current-grouping-key)"/>


                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$current-grouping-key"/>
                        </td>
                        <td/>
                        <td align="right">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(sum($current-group/ItemSum/text())), '#.##')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiv/3 and would output three `tr` elements for your sample, just like the XSLT 2 approach https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiv/0

Comment: For my environment, it only works when the `items-by-description` key is placed inside the  template.

Comment: @J.Olufsen, that sounds rather odd as any `xsl:key` declaration needs to be a top-level element, i.e. a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. Which environment exactly do you use that requires putting `xsl:key` inside of an `xsl:template`?

Comment: The really odd thing that is works but IntelliJ complains about syntax.